# while calling LabVIEW from python, vi.call functions get hold

Tags: python, labview

Currently am trying to call LabVIEW from Python.

here is my code:

```
 import win32com.client  # Python ActiveX Client
 X = 1  # First Number to Add
LabVIEW = win32com.client.Dispatch("Labview.Application")
VI= LabVIEW.getvireference('D:\\labview.vi')  # Path to LabVIEW VI

VI.setcontrolvalue('X', str(X))  # Set Input 1
VI._FlagAsMethod("Call")
**VI.Call()  # Run the VI**
time.sleep(10)
  VI.Abort()
```

Problem is execution get hold at VI.Call() function.

I expect afetr 10 seconds, VI need to Abort. but that is not happening.

Any suggestions

Comment: Did you enable VI server in LabVIEW?

Comment: Is the VI actually running? (You can check this by having the VI throw up a dialog when it starts running... a simple One Button Dialog node will do.) The answer to this question will make a big difference as to the possible solutions.

Comment: Yes Program is running, But couldn't be able to stop VI.